# What is the default log location when no logging provider is specified under Logging (in appsettings.json - example: if I don't provide EventLog)

Tags: asp.net-core

This is the Logging setting in `appsettings.json` file.

The following writes logs to the windows event logs:

```
"Logging": {
  "EventLog": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

What happens when the child node of Logging is not provided. Example:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    }
```

Where does the above setting send the logs to?

Comment: See [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging)

Comment: It says `A specific log provider is not specified, so LogLevel applies to all the enabled logging providers except for the Windows EventLog.` - so which are the enabled logging providers?

Comment: Al of these? `Console
Debug
EventSource
EventLog: Windows only`?

Comment: The logging configuration define only the logging level. Provider is defined in code. Your question can be resume by "What is the default logging level?".

Comment: But my question is - What is the default log location when no logging provider is specified under Logging?

Comment: What do you call "log location"?

Comment: I mean the log destination - which is where the log gets generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger push log according the added providers.

The configuration only define the log level (according to provider/category). It define when the log is pushed, but not where.

---

When the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is used directly, no provider isn't added, then the log is pushed nowhere.

Exemple :

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var logger = LoggerFactory
    .Create(c => { /* No Provider */ })
    .CreateLogger<Logger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("Log something");
```

To log somewhere, you need to add the specific NuGet package and add the provider.

For example, to log in the console, you need to add the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` and specify the provider like :

```cs
var logger = LoggerFactory
    .Create(c => { c.AddConsole(); })
    .CreateLogger<Logger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("Log something");
```

---

But generally, we use a [Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) that manage the configuration, the logging, the dependency injection...

To help to initialize the host, the method `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder` do [a lot of default setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#default-builder-settings). The logging part is :

> Adds the following logging providers:
>
> - Console
> - Debug
> - EventSource
> - EventLog (only when running on Windows)

If you use the host, by default the log is written to these below destinations.

Example :

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
```

Program.cs

```cs
var host = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args).Build();
var logger = host.Services.GetService<Logger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("Log something");
```

---

In ASP.NET Core, we use a `WebHost`. It is a derived of `Host` and the default logging is the same.

Comment: So by default it goes into all the following? Debug
Console
EventSource
EventLog (Windows only) ?

Comment: @variable In ASP.NET Core, yes.

Comment: So then is it right to say in your answer that `By default no provider isn't added, then the log is pushed nowhere.`? Because you then say be default it does go into those 4 locations.

Comment: @variable I edited my answer to add detail. I hope this more understandable.

Comment: what happens if I only specify `  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error"
    }`

Comment: @variable, this sets the log level for all providers (added by code).

Comment: Even if not providers aren't added by code, `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args).Build()` will ensure that it gets logged into the default locations right?

Comment: Yes, it's ensure to add the default providers.

Comment: `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder` is a method (alias reusable code). Not your code, but it's code (there may be conflicting opinions, but it should be considered that way to understand my answer)